# AVID: Mxf with Metadata

Tags: avid

After importing a mp3 file into avid a mxf file with the audio
content gets created.

Sadly all the ID3 metadata informations get lost (not transfered to the new mxf file).

Is there a way or option to transfer all id3 tags to the mxf file?

Comment: Descriptive metadata in MXF files isn't well standardized. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to export and read the id3 tags from the mxf file in order to get artist and title.

Comment: Do you have Interplay or another MAM? I'm not sure there is an automated way to do it with embedded metadata. You might need to export the tags to a sidecar XML.

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about portability of metadata? You could just add some custom columns in the bin and add your metadata there.

If you've never made custom columns you just scroll all the way over to the right, click on the column header, and type in the column name.